# replace an element and its child's with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application ,i am trying to load of e-book chapter pages (like shown html mark up) via ajax req.

My html mark up looks like this :

```
<html><body>
<div id="p5">
<div id="p6">
<p class="heading">heading1</p>
<p class="normal">This is my sample Text here</p>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So after loading the book , i would get all pages in "pageContent" . Now i would like to replace all paragraphs in book with  of same height and width as before. So i did like

```
  $(pageContent).find('p').empty().html('<textarea type ="text"></textarea>')
```

i got textarea with height and width are same as paragraph

element,but i need same height and width as its first parent:

```
   <div id="p6">
```

I do not have any class to this div element and those are id's are different for each page.So i got lost here,So i need something like

```
   <html><body><textarea id= "p6" type ="text"></textarea></html></body>
```

How could i add parents id to my text area and remove that div element.

If you have any questions please add comment, Thanks you so much for your time in advance

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: @ROX, that was my initial thought, but I think the OP simply wants to replace the `div` with a `textarea` that has the same id.

Answer (score 0):

```
//grab the id from the first `div` and then its id
var $div = $('div:first');
var id = $div.attr('id');

// replace the existing div with the textarea
// (complete with id)
$div.replaceWith('<textarea id="' + id + '" type="text"></textarea>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugoj3wuh/1/)

Comment: Hej , thanks a ton man, Sorry i updated my question again,On another page,there is another div on top of it with another id. So far i managed to get id of p6 as :

 var newid= $(pageContent).find('p').parent().attr('id');

but replacing that div with id p6 with same logic does not work

Comment: Hej, managed to fix it with closest(),instead of parent() i used closest('div'). thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this

**HTML**

```
<div id="p6">
    <p class="heading">heading1</p>
    <p class="normal">This is my sample Text here</p>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var newid = $("#p6").attr("id");
$("#p6").parent().html("<textarea id=" + newid + "/></textarea>")
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1pken6zv/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var id = $(pageContent).find('p').closest('div').attr('id');
//want to make sure you have correct id ?
// console.log(id);
$(pageContent).find('p').closest('div').replaceWith('<textarea id = "' + newid +  '" style ="background:#000" type ="text"></textarea>');
```